# Unable to get Office 365 groups I'm a member of via Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to get all the Office 365 groups a user is a member of.
I've registered a 'Native client application' on Azure and selected only one permission: 'Read all groups' under the 'Microsoft Graph' scope.

The problem: users from other tenants got the 'Calling principal cannot consent due to lack of permissions.' error, and did not get to the consent step.

If the user has admin rights or if I register another app on a second tenant, I was able to pass the consent step and also got the groups list.

BTW, registering a 'Web application' and selecting 'Yes' in the Multi-tenant option didn't help either.

Does anybody know if 'Group.Read.All' requires admin consent? According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/application-manifest) it doesn't.
I also tried to run this query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a%20eq%20'unified')` as mentioned [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs) under 'GET unified groups I’m member of', but with no luck.

Another question, is there a way to configure the Native app as a multi-tenant app?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is from what you are saying: Did not get to the consent step and you just selected read all groups are not enough. You have to select sign in users permissions as well in graph api.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried adding the 'Sign in and read user profile' permission but got the same results...

Answer (score 0):

You have a few questions in here, so I'll try to help. Let me know if I've missed something or you need more clarification.

Native applications in Azure AD are multi-tenant by nature, so there's no need to set the multi-tenant toggle like you do with Web apps.

Group.ReadAll does require admin consent. I've found the following page to be super useful as I try to determine the permissions needed for my applications: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes.

During development I have sometimes needed to update the permissions for my app. Whenever permissions are updated I've found it useful to go to http://myapps.microsoft.com to revoke consent for my app. Then the next time I log in to the app, I am always prompted for content so I can clearly see exactly what users will see.

Comment: Than you for the informative answer Doug, however I was not able to find any information about admin consent flow for native applications.

Comment: Admin consent is different than user consent. What happens in this case is your application must send `prompt=admin_consent` with the redirect/HTTP get to `/common/oauth2/authorize`. Here's a great blog post about admin consent in detail. http://blog.mastykarz.nl/implementing-admin-consent-multitenant-office-365-applications-implicit-oauth-flow/

Essentially what will happen is once the admin consents, standard users will not be prompted to consent.

Comment: Indeed, when I use `prompt=admin_consent` with the redirect I was able to consent as an admin and didn't get the prompt as a regular user.
I did it all using a Web App I registered in Azure - do you know if there's a way to achieve this via a Native App?